# "Product updated" web hook for products with SKU sends as many requests as SKUs?

Tags: bigcommerce

I get a lot of requests when I update a product which has SKUs, from my BigCommerce admin panel ..is this by design? Because after a request, I synchronize my product with BigCommerce, but if 12 requests from bigcommerce (12 SKUs), my server starts 12 update threads...which give 429 - to many requests.

What should I do, because I don't seem to receive the SKU id from the BigCommerce request?

Comment: in your code you have to send a http response 200

Comment: @miglio the requests are almost instant (almost at the same time, second etc), so I don't think this is the problem... i send 200 when I finish processing the product update... I don't think they send at such a small interval the update requests....